# echo variable with letter immediately afterwards

Tags: shell

```
p=$( power )
echo "Power now: ${p}W"
```

prints

```
Wower now: 357
```

This makes no sense. Surely this is a bug?

Comment: please add the output from `uname -srv;type power;echo $SHELL $BASH_VERSION` (My WSL2 installation doesn't have a `power` cmd). It's probably that a `\r` char has been introduced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> Wower now: 357
> ```

Ah yes, what this actually is is the following sequence, one byte after the other

```
P (0x50)
o (0x6f)
w (0x77)
e (0x65)
r (0x72)
  (0x20)
n (0x6e)
o (0x6f)
w (0x77)
: (0x3a)
  (0x20)
3 (0x33)
5 (0x35)
7 (0x37)
jump-back-to-beginning-of-line (0x0d) ## called "carriage return", if you know typewriters…
W (0x57)
```

So, your `power` command, for reasons unbeknownst to humankind, outputs `357\r` (carriage return).

Solution: only print things that are actually numbers coming from `power`, for example:

```bash
p=$( power | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' )
echo "Power now: ${p}W"
```

or more compact:

```bash
power | sed -n 's/^\([[:digit:]]*\).*$/Power now: \1 W/p'
```

Comment: AHA! That's what `\r` does! And that kind of explains `\r\n`. And makes Apple's `\r` line endings look pretty odd.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough in the end, I bet these choices simply boil down top which line printer manufacturer the university that the guys designing the ancestors of the apple line of computers had. I **bet** there's someone out there who knows the full story on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com